# Property 'docs' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>[]'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I receive this error in the following code:

> Property 'docs' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot[]'

I am trying to first query a list of users (that are in a collection) from Firestore than use the data to query from an other collection. It seems like I am making an error while updating the list which could be caused by a mistake in query part.

```
const dailyTaskFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('0 0 * * *')
  .timeZone('GMT +3')
  .onRun(async () => {
    const users = await db
      .collection('users')
      .where('location', '==', 'GMT+3')
      .get();
     const taskPromises = users.docs.map((doc) => {
       return db
         .collection('tasks')
         .where('dailyTasks', '==', true)
         .where('completed', '==', true)
         .where('userID', '==', doc.get('userID'))
         .get()
     });
     const taskDocs = await Promise.all(taskPromises);
     const actionsPromises = taskDocs.docs.map((snapshot: { id: string; }) => {
       return db
        .collection('tasks')
        .doc(snapshot.id)
        .set({ completed: false }, { merge: true })
     });
    await Promise.all(actionsPromises);
    return null;
});
```

Comment: Hello, any updates on this question? If my answer was useful you can accept (✔) and upvote () it.  [What should I do when someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The `actionsPromises` is not a `QuerySnapshot` that you can access `.docs` property. It is an array of `QuerySnapshots`. You would have to loop through docs in *each* query snapshot.

```js
    const actionsPromises = []
    taskDocs.forEach((userTasksDocs) => {
      userTasksDocs.docs.forEach((taskDoc) => {
        actionsPromises.push(
          db
            .collection('tasks')
            .doc(taskDoc.id)
            .set({ completed: false }, { merge: true })
        );
      });
    });
    await Promise.all(actionsPromises);
```

Comment: The error is resolved but code doesn't work when triggered